# Could delay in PING cause file descriptors leak?

Tags: java, sockets, networking, jboss

I have java application running on Jboss server.
And i usually see that whenever ping delay i.e network issue happens, file descriptors grow up tremendously and never comes back. It only ends up  in restarting the jvm.
 If PING from the server to the client isn't arriving in time, say it's taking too much time due to network slowness, could it be the cause of FIle Descriptor's leak?

Comment: Could you tell us a bit more about your server's setup? Does it hold files open when waiting for network communication, most importantly?

Comment: Hi @hexafraction, thanks for replying back.
I am using Jboss AS 7.1.1 and have standalone.xml in configuration directory. How and where to check, Does it hold files or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on how the pinging is implemented by your application ....

However, it is plausible that timeouts on a Socket or DatagramSocket could lead to an exception that (if not coded properly) could lead to a file descriptor leak.

Here's an example of the wrong, and then right way to do this kind of thing:

```
// Wrong way
Socket sock = new Socket(...);
sock.connect();
// do stuff including a read that might time out
sock.close();
```

The problem is that the time-out exception is liable to cause the `close()` call to be skipped as control jumps to the handler for the exception ... further up the stack.

```
// Right way (Java 6 and earlier)
Socket sock = new Socket(...);
try {
  sock.connect();
  // do stuff including a read that might time out
} finally {
  sock.close();
}

// Right way (Java 7 and later)
try (Socket sock = new Socket(...)) {
  sock.connect();
  // do stuff including a read that might time out
}
```

In the latter case, there is an *implicit* handler that closes `sock` automatically.

Obviously, you will need to adapt this pattern to what your real code is doing.

Comment: Thanks @Stephen for answering. Can you please tell, What can i do to handle it. If network is ok, then application goes well for days.
The problem only comes when delay in network arises.

Comment: And if possible can you suggest, any tool or way for finding file descriptors leak stacktraces?

Comment: As mostly closing Sockets at all places, How can i change the PING mechanism to not hold the files open when waiting for network?

Comment: Moreover, it's a web based application and not client based.
When sending back response to client, are we dealing with socket connections, i guess these things server would be handling it by itself. please clarify me. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Behaviour of `finally` is basic Java stuff.  You can read about it in any good Java textbook. Closing in `finally` is the simple way to avoid fd leaks.  If you do it another way, you have to analyse your code to ensure that the `close()` always happens.  The rest of your questions don't make sense to me.  I'd need to see the code.

Comment: Thanks Stephen. Most of the places I am using finally for cleaning up, again i will review code if i missed it at some places. 
Just if you can please clear my one doubt or my assumption whatever, Suppose there is a delay in network at server side, thereby client request reaches to server somehow and server processed the request to send back response to the client. But due to network delay at server side, server couldn't send back the response  to client instantly and holds off the response's, waiting to get network. Wouldn't it result in increasing fd's at OS level?

Comment: I don't know.  In part it depends on what kind of ping you are talking about; TCP or UDP based.  (Clearly you are not talking about *real* ICMP PING ... 'cos a Java server wouldn't see those.)

Comment: yes, I am talking about client server communication over HTTP protocol that runs on top of the TCP/IP suite of protocols.

Comment: It seems unlikely.  It is hard to conceive of a networking problem where a server could consistently receive HTTP requests, but get blocked while sending the response.  Do you have **evidence** that your server's threads are blocking while sending response?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47306/discussion-between-ashish-kataria-and-stephen-c)

Comment: Not yet, That's why i said as an assumption. 
Thanks. I will try to review my code and will get back if i found something in regard to this.